# information from a JavaScript site to the NODE.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, api

I have a site in javascript where I get information from a Rest API (JSON)

I would like to make this information available to my server (A node.js that I have created that connects to the database)

It is my first time working with web development; I would like to know how I make the connection between the two?

front end

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <style>     
        .bodyFrame {
            margin: 40px;
        }

        .headerLabel {
            font-weight: bold;
        }

    </style>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="bodyFrame">
        <h2 style="text-align:center;">WIDS JSON Retrieval Example</h2>

        <button type="button" onclick="makeServiceCall()">Retrieve JSON Data</button>
        <br /><br />

        <label class="headerLabel">Programs</label>
        <ul id="programUL"></ul>
    <div>

    <script>

        function makeServiceCall() {                    
            var url = "http://widsservicedev.yaharasoftware.com/WidsService/JSON/GetPortagePrograms/?apikey=104043F0-9C24-4957-879D-046868973CC4&callback";

            $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
                //var myArray = [];
                //myArray[0] = data;
                parseProgramData(data, url);
            });                 
        }

        function parseProgramData(jsonData, url) {      

            $("#dataHeader").empty();
            $("#dataHeader").append('<b>' + url + '</b>');

            var programUL = document.getElementById("programUL");       

            for (var pgmIndex = 0; pgmIndex < jsonData.Programs.length; pgmIndex++) {                   
                var pgmLi = document.createElement("li");
                var program = jsonData.Programs[pgmIndex];
                var programInfoRevision = program.ProgramInfoRevisions[0];
                var numberTitle = programInfoRevision.ProgramNumber + " " + programInfoRevision.ProgramTitle;
                pgmLi.appendChild(document.createTextNode(numberTitle));
                programUL.appendChild(pgmLi);                   

                var linebreak = document.createElement("br");
                pgmLi.appendChild(linebreak);

                var poLabel = document.createElement("label");
                poLabel.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Program Outcomes"));
                poLabel.classList.add("headerLabel");                   
                pgmLi.appendChild(poLabel);                 

                var pgmOutcomeUL = document.createElement("UL");
                pgmLi.appendChild(pgmOutcomeUL);

                for (var poIndex = 0; poIndex < program.ProgramOutcomes.length; poIndex++) {                    
                    var poLi = document.createElement("li");
                    poLi.appendChild(document.createTextNode(program.ProgramOutcomes[poIndex].Description));
                    pgmOutcomeUL.appendChild(poLi);
                }                   
            }

        }
    </script>


</body>

<footer>        
</footer>
```

node.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {

var sql = require("mssql");

// config for your database
/* var config = { user: 'papercut', password: 'Portage.2018', server: 'devsqlcl2:1433', database: 'AgrM6', port: "1433", dialect:",ssql", dialectOptiond:"SQLEXPRESS" };*/

// connect to your database
sql.connect('mssql://xxx:xxxx@xxxx:1433/xxx', function (err) {

    if (err) console.log(err);

    // create Request object
    var request = new sql.Request();

    // query to the database and get the records
    request.query('select * from dbo.balance_papercut', function (err, recordset) {

        if (err) console.log(err)

        // send records as a response
        res.send(recordset);

    });
});
});

var server = app.listen(5000, function () { console.log('Server is running..'); });

Thank you.
```

Comment: You can use websocket connection or make restful API.

Comment: make an AJAX request from your page to your server.

Answer (score 0):

Well to make those data available to the server you basically have to sent a request to the server containing those data. Since you want to sent data to the server you most likely need to use a `POST` request. There are more informations [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp) about how to send such a request.
On the server side you need to an endpoint listening for a post request. You can find a lot of information about how to do this on the server on google.

Comment: If however you want to get the data without making a request to the server you will have to use websockets, which in my opinion is a little more complicated to use since this is your first time in web development.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to accomplish connection between frontend and backend is to create api-endpoints. You have already done so with your `app.get('/', function (req, res)`.

You can do a similar one for sending data to the server. The http method used to send data to the server is generally POST. You can read more about the http methods here:
https://restfulapi.net/http-methods/

A good guide I stumbled upon a few weeks ago are this one:
https://codeforgeek.com/2014/09/handle-get-post-request-express-4/

In this example it does exactly what you're trying to accomplish, by sending data from a script in a static html-file to an Express server.